# Doxygen doesn't generate Qt compressed help file

Tags: qt, doxygen, qthelp

I tried generating a Qt compressed help file thanks to this article: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/08/13/qt-weekly-17-linking-qt-classes-in-documentation-generated-with-doxygen/

Unfortunately, no `qhc` file is generated as specified.

I notice this error in the output log:

```
sh: epstopdf: command not found
error: Problems running epstopdf. Check your TeX installation!
```

Is this article out of date?

Comment: According to the error message you need to install texlive

Comment: I didn't find an easy way to install epstopdf but anyway I don't understand why I need that to generate qhc files